# Can not run Kali VM on Ubuntu host

Tags: drivers, kernel, virtualbox

I attempted to create a Kali virtual machine on Ubuntu, but I cannot start it. Instead of it doing the expected thing and starting, it returns the following error message:

```
Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908)

The VirtualBox Linux kernel driver (vboxdrv) is either not loaded or there is a permission problem with /dev/vboxdrv. Please reinstall the kernel module by executing

'/sbin/vboxconfig'

as root.

where: suplibOsInit what: 3 VERR_VM_DRIVER_NOT_INSTALLED (-1908) - The support driver is not installed. On linux, open returned ENOENT.
```

How can I fix this and get my VM online?

Comment: This question does not seem to be off topic IMO. It's about VirtualBox, not Kali; the fact that it was Kali the OP tried to run in VirtualBox shouldn't matter, right?

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson: On the other hand the issue here is clearly a missing kernel module. There's quite a bit of variance between distributions in that area (though Debian and Kali may happen to be similar enough in this particular case). Additionally this question doesn't add anything for Ubuntu users because we already have heaps of duplicates for it.

Comment: @DavidFoerster: Yeah, maybe it's a duplicate anyway. OTOH then it should be marked as such. I may be oversensitive here, and the reason for it is that I see a tendency to perfunctorily close vote as soon as certain keywords are found in the question.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson that the VirtualBox is running on Ubuntu was added by another user, and there's no evidence for it. I'm rolling back that edit.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential dkms
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge virtualbox-dkms
sudo reboot
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-dkms
```

Thanks for the edit, typing from phone

Comment: Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
build-essential is already the newest version (12.1ubuntu2).
dkms is already the newest version (2.2.0.3-2ubuntu11.3).
linux-headers-generic is already the newest version (4.4.0.53.56).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
N: Ignoring file '50unattended-upgrades.ucf-dist' in directory '/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension

Comment: Try 'sudo modprobe vboxdrv' along with

Comment: when i tyoe the above comment i get this error

Comment: Okay, let's retry.  First, run all the commands as above. Also create a file 'vbox.conf' at /etc/modules-load.d.  Secondly, open the vbox.conf file with text editor and write: vboxdrv vboxnetadp vboxnetflt vboxpci (one in every line, that's 4 lines).  Save and exit.  Thirdly, reboot. Hope it will work now.

Comment: Every time i turn on my laptop on first time it boots a black screen then i will remove the battery on second time the laptop produce login sound but no display and again i remove my battery only on the third time only the screen boot to login screen

Comment: Well, I don't think it's related to kernel parameters. I faced the same with a Lenovo laptop before.

Comment: what is the solution